# How to debug DB2 object

Tags: db2

when I develop application with DB2 I try to debug but can not.

What can I do to debug procedure, function, views, and trigger on DB2.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can debug the SPs using DB2 Developer Workbench.